What's the function of .self in leetcode?
I wrote the program below in Python for question 509 on LeetCode, which asks the user to write a program to find the value of the nth number in the Fibonacci sequence:
class Solution(object):
    def fib(self, n):
        output = 0
        if n == 0:
            output = 0
        elif n == 1:
            output = 1
        else:
            output = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
        return(output)


I was then met with this error:
NameError: global name 'fib' is not defined
    output = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
Line 9 in fib (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().fib(param_1)
Line 30 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 40 in <module> (Solution.py)

I then took a look at all the solutions posted and I noticed that all the solutions that utilized linear recursion had one thing in common: They all used self. as a prefix before calling the fib() function in the body of the initial function. As such, I changed my solution to:
class Solution(object):
    def fib(self, n):
        output = 0
        if n == 0:
            output = 0
        elif n == 1:
            output = 1
        else:
            output = self.fib(n-1) + self.fib(n-2)
        return(output)


The error was gone and LeetCode accepted my submission.
The weird thing is that I ran the initial code without self. in an IDE, and there was no runtime error; the program was working.
Why did I have to use .self in order to get rid of the runtime error on LeetCode?

See here.

On your local computer the code was just a plain standalone function, but for Leetcode you made it into a class.  That's the difference.

When you use def outside class, you are defining a function. If you just had def fib(n) at the top level, fib would be defined as a global function, and you could call it with e.g. fib(4).
However, when you have def inside class, you are defining a method. Welcome to Object Oriented Programming. To access the method, you would first have to instantiate the class, then invoke the method on that instance:
solution = Solution()
solution.fib(4)

The object whose method you are invoking is in Python automatically converted to the first argument. I.e. in Python (and, AFAIK, only in Python) the above is equivalent to
solution = Solution()
Solution.fib(solution, 4)

Since here fib is not a global function, but is tied to the Solution class, the only way to access it is to reference either the Solution class (like in the second example) or one of its instances (like in the first one). (Or one of its descendant classes or their instances.)
self is the traditional name of the instance whose method is being invoked. You could have written def fib(this, n), and then you would have had to say this.fib(n) (and indeed many languages use this where Python conventionally uses self); or you could have written def fib(the_solution_object, n) and then you would need to have the_solution_object.fib(n) when you invoke it. But please don't use anything other than self in Python, or you risk obfuscating your code for future readers.
Now, why is fib made a method of a Solution class, rather than a standalone function? This is a good question. There is no benefit to it here. Classes serve to unify data with behaviours regarding said data. There is no data that the Solution class models, so your method might as well be a function. However, there is also no real downside. The most likely reason is that LeetCode supports many different languages, some where global functions do not exist and everything must be in a class, or that it has other questions where it might be advantageous to apply the object model, at it is easier to treat all questions similarly.
Also, notably, Python prefers to be explicit (or at least claims so). In this case it is true: Python will strictly distinguish a method from a function, and will not assume you meant one when you used the syntax for the other. This is not true for all languages. For example, in Java, you could write this.fib(4) to invoke a method on the current object; but it is more common to just write fib(4), as it usually means the same thing.

In Python, the keyword self. refers to the instance of the class in which the method is being called. When you want to call a method of the same class, you need to use self. to refer to the instance on which the method should be called.
It's the reason why the first code (the error one) has an error NameError: global name 'fib' is not defined. The fib() (without self.) can be known as the global (out of the class) function and you haven't defined it yet.
Conclusion: Use self. when you need to call a class function.

self is not a keyword

You can rename self to foobar and it works too, it's just a convention to name the first parameter of a class method self.
